# Where's the bug in my regex?

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to build a regex that would extract the values of pseudo-xml-tags (enclodes in{} instead of <>) and it doesn't work. Have verified the thing with RegexBuddy, my favourite rx-tool which captured quite correct, but when using it in my PHP-Code, I do not get a result.
So, w/o further ado, here's the problem:

```
$match=array();
$ret=preg_match('\{lang\s*=\s*[\"\']*?(.*?)[\"\']*?\s*/\}',"{lang='DE'/}xxxxlxlxlxl",$match);
```

Why is $match empty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pattern should be

```
/\{lang\s*=\s*[\"\']*?(.*?)[\"\']*?\s*\/\}/
^                                        ^
```

Comment: You forgot to escape the forward slash near the end (since / is used as delimiter, that's why I usually take something like ~)

Comment: @Flo hmm..i don't know php..i had gone through php documentation where i found that `/` is used as delimiter..thanks to point it out

Comment: Ooooooo, missed that :(  Thanks a lot!